# Install lightgbm on windows

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I use `pip to install lightgbm` on windows,Does it work?

Since I have an error while importing LGBMRegressor.
The error shows as below

```
"cannot import name 'LGBMRegressor'"
```

Comment: pip install lightgbm worked for me (windows 10). Would you mind showing us your code/command? Usually you would import lightgbm and then use LGBMRegressor. Can you try to the example from https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/python-guide/simple_example.py , does that work?

Comment: to install 1) git clone 2) compile with visual studio 2015 3) python-package\ :python setup.py install, 4) pip install. pip install only install the python wrapper

Answer (score 12):

I tried installing it using an anaconda environment and was able to install it successfully.

Open Anaconda prompt and type:

```
conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm
```

It will take a few minutes for installation.

Answer (score 3):

I am writing an answer as I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment yet. Valid solutions have been offered but I think that some subtleties should be addressed for those that come here and are new(ish) to Python.

There are differences between pip and conda and if I understand it well, one ought to keep using conda as much as possible within their conda environments to avoid running into time-wasting package conflicts. I advise you read [this article](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/) to get a better grasp on which does what. Myth #2 and #10 are particularly relevant here.

For Lightgbm the obvious solution is to use conda-forge as mentioned above. That is if you are running a conda environment, be it anaconda or miniconda. But you should be aware that for the moment anaconda distribution (AD) and conda-forge (CF) are not 100% compatible, as you can read in [this thread](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7357). From their own words:

> Conda-forge and The Anaconda Distribution are incompatible with each other at present.
>   ...Please pick one or the other for now. CF or AD, never both.

So far it seems not to be a problem for lightbgm though.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

First I used
**`conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm`**
and I got a **`permission error`** so I opened anaconda with administrator privileges.
So it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it worked for me even with Python 3.6

import sys

!{sys.executable} -m pip install lightgbm